# Use PC webcam as Android Camera

Tags: video, android, webcam, camera

I've seen a *lot* of tutorials online on how to use an Android as a webcam for a computer, but none the other way around. Is it possible to use a computer webcam as the video input on an Android, temporarily replacing it's camera? If so, how?

Comment: You might find an answer more quickly if you search over in http://android.stackexchange.com which is the Q&A site for Android.

Comment: Thanks, @K7AAY. There are a lot of posts about using android as a webcam, but only a single unanswered question about a computer being the external camera. I did follow that question, just in case.

Comment: What is your goal? use your pc camera as android camera for all applications? or only in a specific case? You can view your pc camera on the phone via apps, but using it with other native applications wouldn't be possible. the delay in camera access would probably crash most of the apps.

Comment: @Vijay I am looking to use my PC camera as if it were the native android camera, so apps that use the native camera would see my computer webcam.

Comment: sorry out of my depth, you would have to find out at xdaforums or some other android developer community. The latency issues would be a major obstacle, I imagine.